# Setting Animation to trigger on a buttons second click not first click

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, animation, storyboard

I have a frame within my main page that I have set up to stretch/slide over on a button click. I do not want the frame to stretch/slide on the first button click but rather when the user clicks that same button a second time.
XAML:

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="FrameSlide">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="currentPage">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="1.217"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="currentPage">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="-126"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FrameSlideBack">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="currentPage">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.217"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="currentPage">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-126"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>




</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="TransmitBTN">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FrameSlide" Storyboard="{StaticResource FrameSlide}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="PatientBTN">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FrameSlideBack" Storyboard="{StaticResource FrameSlideBack}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

I've tried using the storyboard.stop() / storyboard.being() in my VB.net code for the button, but it seems like the xaml is over ridding the vb code. I've tired doing if statements where my frame is a certain width then do nothing else trigger the animation.
Not sure where to go from here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this in C# as i dont know VB but from what I am told you can change it easily?

The answer I can come with us is make an event on the button, button_click, within the class create a public property. In the event increment the property and when it reaches two, trigger your story board.

XAML for button event:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Click="Button_OnClick"
```

C# code:

```
public partial class StackOverFlowExample
{
   public StackOverFlowExample()
   {
    InitializaComponent();
    buttonClickCounter = 0;
   }

   public int buttonClickCounter {get; set;}

   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     buttonClickCounter++;
     if (buttonClickCounter == 2)
     {
      buttonClickCounter = 0;

      Storyboard sb = Application.Current.Resources["FrameSlide"] as 
      Storyboard;

      if (sb.IsSealed)
          sb = sb.Clone();
      Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, this.NextButton);
      sb.Completed += delegate { };
      sb.Begin();
     }

   e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. I got it working.

Comment: @Elliott No problem :p accept the answer if your happy with it! :p